# Cannot display multiple instances of Java/CSS image gallery on single HTML page

Tags: javascript

JavaScript - I am aware that this is where I need to add something to enable multiple instances to run, however I really have no idea of how to code this correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="kuttinew/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#images_thumbnails a').click(function () {
        var newImageSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#images_full img').attr({
            'src': newImageSrc
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

CSS - This was simple enough

```
#images_full img, 
#images_thumbnails img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#images_thumbnails img {
    margin: 4px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

HTML - Finally the HTML elements

```
<div id="images_full">
    <img src="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="images_thumbnails">
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg">
        <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg">
        <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set03.jpg">
        <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set03.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine until I add a second instance on same HTML page, the second set just open in own window like they have almost by-passed the Java commands.

Comment: do you mean javascript  than java?

Comment: please show an example code of second added instance

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say that your problem is that you are just using ids (#) instead of classes (.) to represent your multiple photo galleries.  If you want similar behavior among multiple "instances," your jQuery script should be acting upon a class instead of an id.  For example:

http://jsbin.com/otiTOyU/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="kuttinew/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$('.images_thumbnails a').click(function () {
  var newImageSrc = $(this).attr('href');
  // Traverse the DOM to change this's respective '.images_full img'
  $(this).parent().prev().children().first().attr('src', newImageSrc);
  return false;
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.images_full img, 
.images_thumbnails img {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.images_thumbnails img {
  margin: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery1">
  <div class="images_full">
    <img src="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="images_thumbnails">
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg">
      <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg">
      <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gallery2">
  <div class="images_full">
    <img src="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="images_thumbnails">
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg">
      <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set01.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="kuttinew/images/full_image/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg">
      <img src="kuttinew/images/thumbnail/kuttison-complete-set02.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are different ways you could go about optimizing the code.  However, I'll leave that to you as an exercise.  Be sure to check out the link I gave near the beginning of my post for a live demo.

Comment: ok why you don't make your comment an answer by putting examples and the answer?

Comment: Welcome Jared Gotte. Your contribution is helpful, and you may very well have answered the question. Please improve your answer and you will start collecting enough rep' to be allowed to comment.

Comment: I added an example to my answer as @imsiso suggested.

Comment: @JaredGotte -  here it is a +1.